Car Alarm Engaged After Remote Start
I have a 2008 Honda accord EX V6 with 155k miles.
I bought this car a year ago, and I saw from Honda invoice and Carfax, the previous owner installed Remote Start from Honda dealer themselves several years ago.
The sequence should have been 3 consecutive locks, and it does remote start but the car alarm also goes off, which is a pain in the neck.
The workaround I found is to do 3 locks then hold the unlock button, which disengages the car alarm because by holding unlock, my driver door is left unlocked and the car also remote starts without any issue.
Anyone know why the alarm goes off after the standard way of remote starting, 3 locks? Is there a way to disable it perhaps?
Important Edit: There have been a few instances of where the alarm did NOT go off after I remote started it, I cannot figure why the alarm didnt go off those occasions, but this is infrequent, most of the time the alarm is always going off after 3 locks.

Tried asking the Honda dealer that installed remote start? It might help if you have remote start literature identifying the manufacturer.

Good point, issue is the Honda that did it is in a different state, in PA and about 4 hours away from me, I will try asking my local Honda, but I’m not sure what to expect from their support as this install was done like 6 years ago…

You can try calling the Pa Honda for help. Anticipate the worst if they can't 'remember' what they installed, especially if remote start was an aftermarket system. expect the best if they do remember and have info to pass on to you. Otherwise, you may have to poke around under the steering column for the system unit that doesn't fit in with factory wiring. It may have labeling for clues.

Does pressing 4 or more lock signals while near the car instantly set off the alarm? Like a panic alarm maybe? Check the documentation for that. If so, one or more of your 3 remote presses may be interpreted as 2 presses because you are just on the fringe of acceptable range and the signal fades and returns during the keypress. If that's the case, a new remote battery may help, getting closer may help, or pressing the remote into the angle of your jaw or the tip of your chin may help to increase transmitter range. Not kidding, it works.

Yes 4 or more sets of the alarm too, ill try that out
